# tensor product, isotropic

Tags: tensors, tensor-rank

Assume that $T_{ijkl}$ is a 4-th rank isotropic tensor. Why is it $\epsilon_{ijk}T_{ijkl}=0$, without assuming the general formula for a 4-th rank isotropic tensor $\alpha \delta_{ij}\delta_{kl}+\beta\delta_{ik}\delta_{jl}+\gamma\delta_{il}\delta_{jk}$?

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint, both $T$ and $\epsilon$ are isotropic tensors. Is their contraction also isotropic?

Comment: Isn't their contraction 0?

Comment: Their contraction is 0. The possible way to show this is to check if the contraction is isotropic and check its rank.